# Plot list over same x values?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list that looks like this:

```
list = {{2}, {3}, {5, 2}, {9, 3, 5}};
```

I want a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @Nasser no, that's not what I want--I'd like the numbers grouped together in the list to be plotted right on top of each other, as shown in the picture.

Comment: Ok, will think more.

Answer (score 7):

```
list = {{2}, {3}, {5, 2}, {9, 3, 5}};
ListPlot@Flatten[#, 1] &@(Tuples /@ MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, list])
```

[image]

Or in case you want them to have different colors:

```
ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Orange}] &@
      (Tuples/@MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, list])
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

How about this?  At least until a better solution shows up?

```
list = {{2}, {3}, {5, 2}, {9, 3, 5}};
r = Table[{Red, PointSize[.02], Point[{i, #}] & /@ list[[i]]}, {i,Length[list]}];
Graphics[r, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {{2}, {3}, {5, 2}, {9, 3, 5}};

n = 1; list2 = Thread[{n++, #}] & /@ list

(*  {{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3, 5}, {3, 2}}, {{4, 9}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}}}  *)

ListPlot[list2, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to BlacKow's answer, in that `MapIndexed[]` is the key function for adding the abscissas:

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Transpose[PadRight[{#2, #1}, Automatic, #2]] &, list],
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: clusters of different points]

If they are meant to be part of just one set of data, add a `Flatten[]`:

```
ListPlot[Flatten[MapIndexed[Transpose[PadRight[{#2, #1}, Automatic, #2]] &, list], 1],
         AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: clusters all together]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to use `MapIndexed`:

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, list],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[.03], PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

or `MapThread`

```
ListPlot[MapThread[Thread[{##}] &, {Range@Length@list, list}],
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[.03], PlotRange -> Full, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

```
list = {{2}, {3}, {5, 2}, {9, 3, 5}};

ListPlot[PadLeft[list, Automatic, ""]\[Transpose]]
```

[image]

Add e.g. `PlotStyle -> Blue` for uniform styling:

[image]